# Django error: cannot import name current_datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm Working through "The Django Book" and I keep getting the error "cannot import name current_datetime"

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from mysite.views import current_datetime, hello

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    ('^hello/$', hello), 
    ('^time/$', current_datetime),
    (r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
)
```

My Views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My working directory:

```
./mysite:
__init__.py manage.py   mysite      views.py
```

No matter what I do, I get the same import error in urls.py line 2, regarding current_time:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/jvieitez/Code/djcode/mysite/mysite/urls.py" in <module>
  2. from mysite.views import hello, current_datetime, hours_ahead

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name current_datetime
```

Comment: just about to say the same thing, indentation is not correct

Comment: Would you mind telling me what it should look like? I am copying it straight from http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html  Thank you!

Comment: What is `mysite` in the folder `mysite`? Is it also a folder? If so, does it contain `__init__.py`?

Comment: @nymk yes, I recently copied `__init__.py` to both folders per some other thread's suggestion.

Comment: The outer `mysite` package was shadowed by the inner `mysite`. The `mysite` in `from mysite.views import current_datetime, hello` was resolved to the inner one.

Comment: As per your question about how the indentation should look, just look at your post. It's been fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something is wrong with your working directory.  manage.py and views.py should not be in the same directory.  I would recommend renaming the inner mysite to something else, so you avoid the confusion, and views.py should be in the *inner* mysite directory.  You said

```
from mysite.views import current_datetime, hello
```

but views.py isn't in the mysite directory.  That's the problem.

Comment: Bam! Solved! That was the problem. Thanks so much!

I was editing the `views.py` located in the outer `mysite` folder rather than the other `mysite` contained in that one. I will definitely have to rename them. Thank you!